AWS Lambda Custom JWT Validation

I've built that first validates the JWT Token and then extracts the user unique ID ("sub").
In a non Lambda environment the script works fine, however in the AWS Lambda I'm having an error message.
What could be the problem?

Unexpected error during JWT validation: Unable to find an algorithm
for key: {'alg': 'RS256', 'e': 'AQAB', 'kid':
'dmAQX7bVDINFkTGxZc5YCxF5ZA/pcaRsQMUoBbRt4bw=', 'kty': 'RSA', 'n':
'u9hHbyMaI-PWsTG9MtaHjxwBmMez6VeV-ScqIgllBUSQkx8Ao...vGUIG39rb3nPmNVCunBw',
'use': 'sig'}

This is my AWS Lambda code:
import json
import os
import requests
from jose import jwt, jwk

def get_efs_keys(file_name="/mnt/efs/jwks.json"):
    
    # The jkws.json is obtained from here:
    # https://cognito-idp.<Region>.amazonaws.com/<userPoolId>/.well-known/jwks.json
    
    try:
        with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
            jwks_data = json.load(file)
            return jwks_data.get('keys', [])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while fetching keys: {e}")
        return []

def validate_jwt(jwt_token, keys):
    if not jwt_token:
        return False, False

    try:
        headers = jwt.get_unverified_headers(jwt_token)
        kid = headers.get('kid')
        if not kid:
            return False, False

        key = next((key for key in keys if key['kid'] == kid), None)
        if key is None:
            return False, False

        public_key = jwk.construct(key)
        decoded_token = jwt.decode(jwt_token, public_key, algorithms=['RS256'], audience=os.environ.get('APP_CLIENT_ID'))
        return True, decoded_token.get('sub', False)
    except jwt.JWTError as e:
        print(f"JWT token validation error: {e}")
        return False, False
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error during JWT validation: {e}")
        return False, False

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Get all headers from the event
    headers = event.get('headers', {})

    # Get the Authorization header
    authorization_header = headers.get('Authorization', '')

    # Parse the Bearer token to get only the access token (case-insensitive)
    if authorization_header.lower().startswith('bearer '):
        access_token = authorization_header[7:]
    else:
        access_token = None

    # Get keys from EFS
    keys = get_efs_keys()

    # Validate the JWT token
    jwt_valid, sub = validate_jwt(access_token, keys)

    # Create a response
    response_body = {
        'access_token': access_token,
        'jwt_valid': jwt_valid,
        'sub': sub
    }

    response = {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        'body': json.dumps(response_body)
    }

    return response

If the validation is successful, the "jwt_valid" must be "True" and the "sub" the respective unique value.

This thread suggests that you are missing the dependency cryptography.
E.g. you need to install it in your Lambda layer because it provides the necessary algorithms.
pip install cryptography


Thanks mate, you saved my day! It worked after installing cryptography :-)
